# How is change gray color in mat-tabs and set black

Tags: angular-material

I have mat-tab-group and two mat-tabs. Now when one of them is not active, it has gray color. I need to do color of text in tab black. But I can not do this because the color still grey when the tab is not active.

I tried `::ng-deep` and `:host` and `!important`, but tabs still grey.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using ng-deep as it is deprecated:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Instead, you should style it as the angular material docs:

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Since you will probably have a lot of custom styles for your material componentes, its a better aproach, and you can centralize all of the material custom styles in a single scss file if you want.

Example of a implementation (not tested, but it should work):

my-custom-elements.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin custom-tabs-theme() {
   // First tab
  .mat-tab-label.nth-child(1)  {
    background-color: red;
  }
   // Second tab
  .mat-tab-label.nth-child(2)  {
    background-color: red;
  }
   // All tabs
  .mat-tab-label  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

global-material-theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

@import './material/my-custom-elements.scss';

@include custom-tabs-theme();
angular.json

...
"styles": ["src/styles.scss", "src/app/global-material-theme.scss"]
...
```

Note: You can edit any material css class this way.

Note: this will change the style for all tabs in the app, if you want a different approach you need to manipulate by class in your mat-tab-group element, and access the

```
...
.your-class .mat-tab-header .mat-tab-label-container 
.mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label.nth-child(1)
...
```